# How to set input files with a Makefile? (C)

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, compilation

If I have source code files `main.c`, `library.c`, `library.h`, etc. how would I go about setting the input text files to act as console commands like `main input1.txt input2.txt`? Can this be done at all or must it be done post-compilation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
program: main.c library.c  
     gcc -o program $<

.PHONY: run
run: program input1.txt input2.txt.  
     ./program input1.txt input2.txt
```

Basically, you treat them like dependencies for running the program. In the above example, `make run` will run the program and compile it if needed.

Comment: I get a `Makefile:3: *** missing separator.  Stop.` despite changing the spaces to tabs, is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think it's needing a colon after PHONY. I was going from memory :)

Comment: It is a common practice to use `$@` instead of `program` in the recipe of the `program` target, that way you don't need to change the recipe if the name of the target is changed (as you already did with `$<` for the prerequisites). For more info, see the available *automatic variables* in  https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html

Comment: I think you actually meant `$^` instead of `$<` in your first recipe.